# Bridging two VPN networks

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, wireguard

I have a raspberry into my home network. The home network has a public IP, so I can reach my raspberry with a NAT rule in my router and thus create a VPN connection where the raspberry is the Wireguard server and my phone is the client. No problems doing that.

I also set up a connection between the raspberry and a server of a VPN provider using the OpenVPN protocol, so the raspberry is the client that successfully connects to the VPN server somewhere in the world.

Now I want to "join" the Wireguard tun to the OpenVPN tun. My ultimate goal is to have a private connection from a device of mine to my house network (where other services run) and from there to the server of the VPN provider.

I'm a bit confused about how to do it. Should I just set the rules on iptables NATting the two nets or create routes? Or should I perform some other operation?

I have only one physical interface and my config is the following:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:be:3f:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.142/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 54463sec preferred_lft 54463sec
    inet6 2001:b07:5d33:80a:dea6:32ff:febe:3f4f/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:febe:3f4f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:be:3f:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
    inet 10.6.0.1/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.203.8.54/24 brd 10.203.8.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3db:1b4c:f152:ac9c/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: tun2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.203.17.206/24 brd 10.203.17.255 scope global tun2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dbfb:9700:bb06:c263/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.203.56.142/24 brd 10.203.56.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::91f:9469:616a:8360/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: on the OpenVPN endpoint upstream, are you just connecting to a single server, or are you trying to reach the whole network on the other end of that tunnel? are all three networks using different IP network address ranges? you will likely need to set routes at you Pi, your phone, and on the  OpenVPN server upstream, as well as some IP tables accept rules, and if you want the device to act as a NAT router (to make the server act as a router for your VPN clients) you will also need a masquerade configuration. DNS resolution may be difficult in this scenario. you may need a bind server on-lan.

Comment: I've just connected to a single server. That's working out of the box since it's a premium service. Yeah, kinda complicated all this stuff. Your suggestions btw confirm my direction. Thanks, @FrankThomas